# OpenApi schema for JsonIdentityReference-normalized JPA Entities

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, openapi, springdoc

Using @RestController, CrudRepository and glue @Services, I provide access to some JPA-based objects.

The `User` class references a `List<Order>` while the `Order` references the `User`.

To break jackson infinite recursion loops, I replace nested objects via `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)`. However, springdoc seems to ignore it, and still produces OpenApi Spec which points to `Order` instead of, e.g. `Long` (the id class).

How to tell springdoc to map `User.orders` to `List<Long>` or (even better) to `List<OrderId>`?

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))))
    })
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>> listUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users.findAll());
    }

    // getters and setters omitted

}

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class User {

    @Schema(description = "The id of the user", required = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private List<Order> orders = Collections.emptyList();

    // getters and setters omitted
}


@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Schema(required = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private List<Product> products = Collections.emptyList();

    // getters and setters omitted

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution (breaks the semantics): Add the `@ArraySchema` to the defintion like this:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Long.class))
    private List<Order> orders = Collections.emptyList();
```